# Ruby Code not being executed

Tags: ruby, svn, svn-checkout

i'm trying to upload some files to a svn repository with ruby.
But after checking out, the rest of the code is not being executed.

```
r = SvnRepository.new("#{repDir}")
r.checkout("", ".", user, pass)

puts "NOT EXECUTING!"
`cp -r #{compFold} ./trunk/#{compFold}`
r.add("trunk", "./#{compFold}")
r.commit("trunk", "Component #{compFold} uploaded", user, pass)
```

r.checkout code:

```
def checkout(repository, working_copy_path, user = nil, pass = nil)
    #result = `cd #{working_copy_path} && #{@svn} co file:///#{@repository_base}/#{repository}`
    check = "cd #{working_copy_path} && #{@svn} co #{@repository_base}/#{repository}"
    if user != nil
        check = check + " --username #{user}"
        if pass != nil
            check = check + " --password #{pass}"
        end
    end

    result = exec(check)
    result[/d+/]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `exec` inside `checkout` replaces the current process with one for the program being executed. Hence, `exec` never returns. See [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-exec) for more detail.

You can replace `exec` with `spawn` to enable you to execute a process separate from your controlling process. Calling `spawn` will return the pid of the new process that you can then monitor using `Process`.

Comment: What are you saying it's true.
But i'm not trying to execute different threads.
It works correctly changing **exec(check) for \`#{check}\`**.